# How to use OpenCL

Tags: opencv

※ I'm japanese and beginner of this service.

#### ■Introduction

Hello. I'm an image process software developer and using OpenCV3.2.0.

I intend to use OpenCL. Thus I built the OpenCV by CMake as shown below.

```
OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
  Include path:                C:/opencv/opencv320/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
  Use AMDFFT:                  NO
  Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
```

#### ■What I tried

I did some image process test.

> CPU: Intel Xeon E5645 2.40GHz
>
> iGPU: -
>
> dGPU: amd firepro w9100

***TEST 1: cv::add()***

argMat = png, 16bit, 1ch, 8000x8000

```
void class::mf_plus(const double argVal, cv::Mat* argMat)
{
    cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(m_enableUMat);

    cv::UMat tmpMat;
    (*argMat).copyTo(tmpMat);

    cv::add(tmpMat, cv::Scalar(argVal), tmpMat);

    tmpMat.copyTo(*argMat);
}
```

Speed measurement (10 times)

m_enableUMat = true

|281ms|93ms|94ms|94ms|93ms|78ms|93ms|93ms|94ms|94ms|

m_enableUMat = false

|296ms|281ms|281ms|280ms|296ms|281ms|296ms|281ms|296ms|296ms|

***TEST 2: cv::minMaxLoc()***

argMat = png, 16bit, 1ch, 8000x8000

```
void class::mf_minMax(cv::Mat* argMat, double* argMin, double* argMax)
{
    cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(m_enableUMat);

    cv::UMat tmpMat;
    (*argMat).copyTo(tmpMat);

    cv::minMaxLoc(tmpMat, argMin, argMax);
}
```

Speed measurement (10 times)

m_enableUMat = true

|202ms|109ms|110ms|125ms|109ms|109ms|109ms|110ms|109ms|109ms|

m_enableUMat = false

|172ms|172ms|172ms|171ms|171ms|171ms|171ms|171ms|172ms|187ms|

***TEST 3: cv::matchTemplate()***

m_matProc = png, 16bit, 1ch, 8000x8000

argMat = png, 16bit, 1ch, 4000x4000

```
void class::mf_templateMatching(cv::Mat& argMat)
{
    cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(m_enableUMat);

    cv::UMat tmpMatSource, tmpMatTemplate, matResult;
    m_matProc.convertTo(tmpMatSource, CV_32F);
    argMat.convertTo(tmpMatTemplate, CV_32F);

    cv::matchTemplate(tmpMatSource, tmpMatTemplate, matResult, CV_TM_SQDIFF);
}
```

Speed measurement (10 times)

m_enableUMat = true

|6162ms|6162ms|6162ms|6162ms|6162ms|6193ms|6099ms|6177ms|6193ms|6116ms|

m_enableUMat = false

|5788ms|5522ms|5475ms|5491ms|5554ms|5492ms|5491ms|5538ms|5507ms|5523ms|

#### ■Question

**Q1.**

At CMake log, what's the AMDFFT and the AMDBLAS?
If it marks NO, does OpenCL work properly?

**Q2.**

When m_enableUMat = true, why does processing time increase only 1st time?

**Q3.**

In spite of using high end GPU, their are not much effect I supporsed.
Do I get the benefits of OpenCL properly?
Is there a way to check it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed similar behaviour when trying to use openCL with openCV. I also use a custom build without AMDFFT and AMDBLAS.
Have you tried using the pre-built dll's?

Comment: Maybe the longer runtime on the first call has something to do with run-time compilation of the kernel: https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS/wiki/Pre-compilation-vs-run-time-compilation-in-OpenCL